# Install poppler in AWS base python image for Lambda

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, aws-lambda, poppler-utils

I am trying to deploy my docker container on AWS Lambda. However, I use `pdf2image` package in my code which depends on `poppler`. To install `poppler`, I need to insert the following line in the Dockerfile.

```
RUN apt-get install -y poppler-utils
```

This is the full view of the dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y poppler-utils

RUN apt-get install python3 -y
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /

COPY app.py .
COPY requirements.txt  .

RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "app.py" ]
```

However, to deploy on Lambda, I need to use AWS base python image for Lambda. This is my attempt to rewrite the above dockerfile to use the Lambda base image.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.6

# Cannot run the follow lines: apt-get: command not found

# RUN apt-get update
# RUN apt-get install -y poppler-utils

COPY app.py .
COPY requirements.txt  .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["app.handler"]
```

Based on the dockerfile above, you can see that the apt-get command cannot be run. Understandable because it is not from ubuntu image like I did earlier. My question is, how can I install the `poppler` in the Lambda base image?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It uses the yum package manager, so you can do the following instead:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.6

RUN yum install -y poppler-utils
```