# apk-get error-- command not found on aws lambda image

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker

I am trying to build and upload my lambda container,but if fails on line **RUN apt-get** --command not found

I also tried with  **Run apk**  but it fails too with error --command not found

How can I install my package with **public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.7** ?

```
FROM  public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.7

WORKDIR /code


COPY . .
COPY policy.xml /etc/ImageMagick-6

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt install -y tesseract-ocr-heb
RUN apt-get -y install ghostscript

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

I also tried with

1. **Run apk**  but it fails too with error --command not found
2. Run yum install -y tesseract-ocr-heb and got error--
   One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
   #4 1.327  and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install poppler in AWS base python image for Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70832297/install-poppler-in-aws-base-python-image-for-lambda)

Comment: I'm using windows OS  and yum is not recognized

Comment: You have to run `yum` inside of the container using the Dockerfile.

Comment: I did but got an error one of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
#4 1.327  and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue.

Comment: Interesting… Could you [edit] your answer to add that, please?

Answer (score 1):

You should use yum package manager.

Here are the commands for installing tesseract on OpenSuse:
https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/InstallationOpenSuse.html 
add  `--nogpgcheck` flag  to skip key check.

Here is how your dockerfile should look like:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.7

RUN yum install -y yum-utils

RUN yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Alexander_Pozdnyakov/RHEL_7/
RUN yum update
RUN yum install -y tesseract --nogpgcheck
RUN yum install -y tesseract-langpack-heb --nogpgcheck



WORKDIR /code
COPY . .
COPY policy.xml /etc/ImageMagick-6
RUN yum install -y ghostscript


RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


EXPOSE 80
CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```